# ros jade and gazebo 5.0 migration problem

Tags: ros, installation, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to upgrade from ros indigo to ros jade. I followed the following procedure

```
sudo apt-get get remove ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

then

```
sudo apt-get get install ros-jade-desktop-full
```

However, when I am trying to launch a simulation with gazebo I obtain the following error

> /opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver: 22: .: Can't open /share/gazebo//setup.sh

> /opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient: 17: .: Can't open /share/gazebo//setup.sh

> [gazebo-2]
> process has died [pid 5171, exit code
> 2, cmd
> /opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver
> -e ode /home/mago/Projects/2015a_Nicastro_HeterogeneousMultirobot/src/uav/worlds/vtol.world
> __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/mago/.ros/log/0b588c00-6078-11e5-b34f-f04da268d7ae/gazebo-2.log]. log file:
> /home/mago/.ros/log/0b588c00-6078-11e5-b34f-f04da268d7ae/gazebo-2*.log

Apparently it can't find the file  /share/gazebo//setup.sh
I noticed the double slash, therefore I tried to search the setup.sh file manually.
However, the command

```
ls /usr/share/ | grep gazebo
```

gives

> gazebo-3.0

> gazebo-5.0

Moreover, in the "gazebo-5.0" folder there is no file "setup.sh"

I think something went wrong during the installation, I tried to remove everything and reinstall but without success.
Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I tried the workaround described [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/323), but apparently I have libgazebo5-dev already installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217970/ros-jade-and-gazebo-5.0-migration-problem/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, installing the gazebo5 package seems to have solved the problem. However I do not understand why this was necessary. Isn't the package  ros-jade-desktop-full supposed to install it?

Thank anyway

Andrea

---

Originally posted by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) with karma: 385 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2015-10-09**:
Hi, i had the same problem `sudo apt-get install gazebo5` solved it :-)